# Proving a complex numbers result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> $z$ is defined as $z=a+bi$.
>
> Show that $|z|^2=zz^*$ and $(z-ki)^*=z^* +ki$.
>
> In an argand diagram a set of points representing the complex number $z$ is defined by the equation $|z-10i|=2|z-4i|$.
>
> Show by squaring both sides, that $zz^*-2iz^*+2iz-12=0$. Hence show that $|z-2i|=4$.

I was able to do the first two parts easily. For the second part I squared both sides and after tidying up, I arrived at $z^2-2zi+12=0$. I know that I have to use the results that I proved in the first part but I can't see how I can do that.

Comment: What is $z^\ast$? If $z^\ast=\bar{z}$, then you're going to have a hard time showing $|z|=zz^\ast$. Is $k$ assumed to be real?

Comment: k is real and $z^*$  is the conjugate of$ z$

Comment: Note that $|z|^2=zz^*$, not $|z|=zz^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the result you just proved!

$$|z-10i|=2|z-4i|$$

becomes

$$(z-10i)(z^*+10i)=4(z-4i)(z^*+4i)$$

Did you get that? I think you must not have, judging from your attempt. Can you take it from there?

It should be obvious, you just proved $|z|^2 = zz^*$ and $(z−ki)^*=z^*+ki$, therefore

$$|z-10i|^2=(z-10i)(z-10i)^*=(z-10i)(z^*+10i)$$

Comment: how do I prove the last part?

Comment: Add 16 to both sides of the equation. Then factorise the left side into $(z-2i)(z^*+2i)$. Then it should be obvious

Comment: If you've wondering as to how to come up with adding 16 to both sides, you start with knowing you want to put the equation in the form $|z+xi|=a$ so you have to factorise the equation like $(z+fi)(z^*-fi)$. The only way to do this is such that $f=2$. You then work out $(z+2i)(z^*-2i)$ and see the difference with $zz^*-2iz^*+2iz-12=0$. We get  $(z+2i)(z^*-2i) = zz^*-2iz^*+2iz+4$. The difference between $zz^*-2iz^*+2iz-12=0$ and $(z+2i)(z^*-2i) = zz^*-2iz^*+2iz+4$ is 16. So adding 16 to both sides will allow you to factorise the left side in the form $(z+fi)(z^*-fi)$